# SQL Server Patch Level Is Inaccurate, Causing Upgrade Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, upgrade, service-pack

I have a box that lists SQL Server 2014 SP2 (12.2.5000) in both add/remove programs and the registry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\SQLServer2014\CurrentVersion\PatchLevel

However, if I run `SELECT @@VERSION` it returns `12.0.2000`. If I look at the *sqlsrvr.exe* it also lists `12.0.2000`.

Doing some testing I can get a machine in this state (not sure if this is how it happened in production).

1. Windows 7 SP1 image with SQL Server 2014 RTM (12.0.2000)
2. Execute SQL Server 2014 SP2 installer as an upgrade (non-automated)
3. Once on the accept license screen, cancel the install
4. Reboot the machine

The big problem is that if I execute the SQL Server 2014 SP2 upgrade package against this machine nothing is upgraded. What are my options? Do I just need to tear out SQL Server and install clean? I would love to avoid that if possible as this will have to happen at 200+ locations

EDIT:
Okay, so this is where I say I'm not a DBA and I figured out what was happening. Apparently the "Upgrade" option does not upgrade the instance. Still doing some reading on that, but I can "add features to an existing instance" and get things upgraded. Still digging through, I will post an answer once I have everything squared away. Thank you for all the suggestions thus far.

EDIT 2:
At current this is the installer that was used.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167
When running through this upgrade the "Upgrade from SQL Server 2005, 2008, etc. option is chosen. I believe this is the issue at it appears to just updgrade Shared Features? I could use this installer and go through the add features to an existing installation and select the appropriate instances.

I believe this is the installer we should be using as it is a patch to SP2.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168
Select all instances and go. Seems easier.

Did I break this down about right?

Comment: It sounds like the registry needs to be restored but I would definitely get Microsoft’s opinion before you do that If you have no testing environment.

Comment: This sounds like an upgrade bug that Microsoft would probably like to know about, too.

Comment: When you say "restored" do you mean from a registry backup of the machine? Our best theory right now is that this happened about 15 months ago, I do not have any registry backups from that time.

Comment: What would be the best method to report this bug to Microsoft?

Comment: If this isn't production and you're only testing then try to change the registry key to the same value as @@version

Comment: Only make a backup of your current broken registry environment before you do that. :/. If it did work, the you could export the change to the registry in a .reg file and automate this across all the environments. Assuming they really did not have that new upgrade

Comment: Let me try that on my VM. Again, my reproduction is my way of getting into what appears to be the same state.

Comment: I think you should look at your setup bootstrap logs as well before you make any registry changes. Every setup run from landing page to end of it produces a summary.txt and detail.txt files. You should look into these files to understand exactly what happened first. Its possible that a setup performed registry changes but did not complete the installation.

Comment: If I change the registry entry listed above and run the upgrade it is not actually upgraded. The @@VERSION remains 12.0.2000.
Also, the registry entry I changed stayed the same.

Comment: @samosql I am pulling those logs from production right now. I do not have direct access so it will be a bit. Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be a dummy and run the right stuff. Using this patch https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168 and this command everything works great.

> C:\FILELOCATION\SQLServer2014SP2-KB3171021-x64-ENU.exe /qs /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances